ReactSwitch is not displaying the switch in the Browser
I am new to React and i am using ReactSwitch to display switch option. But i am not seeing the switch in the browser. But it seems like working when i click it. Not sure i am missing any plugins or supported modules in browser.
import ReactSwitch from 'react-switch'

<ReactSwitch 
height ={20}
width = {20}
handleDiameter={18}
checked = {includeUpperCase}
onChange={()=>setIncludeUpperCase(!includeUpperCase)}
/>



share your full code please

It's better to delete this and edit your question

Edit your question to add the full code
